# KnockoutJS data-bind attr to a function doesn't seem to work

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to data-bind an attribute with KnockoutJS to a function, so I can do some string manipulation, and struggling to get it to work.

The following works perfectly fine:

```
<div data-bind="html: doSomething($data)></div>
```

However, the following does not:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { src: doSomething($data)}">link</a>
```

Could somebody please help me get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are possibly a couple of problems that you might be facing.

First, you should use `href` instead of `src` for an anchor's link.

Second, where does `doSomething` live?  Is it a global function?  Does it live on each item in an array or on the top-level view model.  If it lives on the root view model, then you can refer to it using `$root.doSomething` from within the scope of an item that you are doing a `foreach` on.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WbxPm/

Comment: sorry, I typed up the question quickly without thinking, it is a 'href' that I am using, but as I was also sorting out some images at the same time, I must of typed out 'src' by mistake.

As for the doSomething method, it exists as a global function, so I cannot seem to access it no matter what I do.

Comment: I would try to reproduce your scenario based on my fiddle, if possible.  There is not quite enough code in your question to make many more suggestions.  Also, are you getting an error?  Is it reaching your function or saying that it is not found?

Comment: Here's basically what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/JustinN/WbxPm/2/ - which gives the error Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined;

Comment: In the fiddle, under Choose Framework, select "no wrap (body)".  Currently the js code is run onLoad, which means that it is executed in a function so doSomething is not global.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it all works like a charm now. I also plan on having a read through the articles on your website, thanks again.